# Applying languages / locale selectively: is it possible?

Tags: 10.10, internationalization

I am a Dutch user and prefer the my local date & time format, system wide. I have no trouble speaking or understanding English and find it very useful to have the rest of my system configured in English to make my life easier when I need to Google a term, for example.

Is it possible to apply the a local date/time/currency/etc. format to the system, while maintaining English menu & dialog captions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abolutely,

- go to *System → Administration → Language Support*
- at *Language*, select English as your default language:

  [image]
- And in the *Text* tab, choose Dutch as your preffered Locale for numbers, dates and currency.

  [image]

I've been using this setting for a long time, and it's a bit weird sometimes, you may see something like "This file was modified on Maandag...", but it works very well with most apps.

After a bit of troubleshooting, it turns out you also have to:

- Click 'Apply System-Wide'
- Reboot

Comment: It's System->Administration->Language Support in my system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually did this and expected it to work, but my settings are still set to English for some reason. I tried applying system-wide and rebooting, without success.

Comment: Please post the output of `locale` to [a pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and add it to your question, I just noticed [mine](http://paste.ubuntu.com/560948/) is a bit strange.

Comment: @Stefano you have selected German, not Dutch. At least in the screen-shot and according to the pastebin. Dutch would be nl_NL.

Comment: @Stefano added the output. Not surpring, but still strange: output seems to indicate en.US only even though I did not configure it this way...

Comment: @Pit, yeah, that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You have to restart you system (several times) for "Changes to take effect".

Comment: @Aron, the preview in the language settings looks correct, are you sure you have all of the correct language packages installed? (`sudo apt-get install language-pack-gnome-nl`)

Comment: @Stefano, sadly, yes. The packages *seem* to be installed correctly as `apt-get install` also results in an 'already at newest version' message. Could it perhaps be a corrupted install?

Comment: @Aron, that's very improbable. I'm sorry I've no idea why it's not working. You _could_ try to remove the dutch language pack after making sure that dutch is selected as the default on the gdm login screen (that's very hacky, but it _might_ work). I've noticed that on my system, I don't have the german language pack installed (maybe my behaviour is erroneous)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it seems to work now.

**What I did:**

- **Click 'Apply System-Wide'**
- **Reboot**

I'd swear I did this before, but logic is against me.

Comment: I'm glad that did it! I've added those two steps to my answer so that it now explains the whole thing.

Comment: Guys I already commented on the first answer that you have to restart you system (several times) for "Changes to take effect". There is even a notice under the language-drop-down menu saying "Changes take effect the next time you log in"

Answer (score 0):

### For Ubuntu 11.10

- Go to *System setings → Language Support*
- At *Language*, select English as your default language
- Click *Install/ remove languages...*
- Make sure the language you want for your date, time and currency is installed
- Go to the *Regional formats* tab to select your preferred locale for time, date and currency
- Ignore the error in the example
- Click *Apply system-wide* and reboot